# Why dont I need to call services.AddMediatr()?

Tags: autofac, mediatr

I have an Web API application that uses both Mediatr and Autofac.

In my Startup.ConfigureServices method I have:

```
void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    services.AddMediatR(executingAssembly);
}
```

In my Startup.ConfigureContainer() I have:

```
        builder.RegisterModule(new MediatorModule());
        builder.RegisterModule(new ApplicationModule("Connection String"));
```

In my MediatorModule based on Autofac I have:

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    Guard.Against.Null(builder, nameof(builder));

    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    // Register Repository class
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IJobSeekerRepository<JobSeeker>).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    // Register Event Service
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IJobSeekerMgmtEventService).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces();

    // Commands Handlers
    builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(AddCreditCardCommand).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>));

    // Domain Events 

builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(JobSeekerRegisteredDomainEventRelayHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
        .AsClosedTypesOf(typeof(INotificationHandler<>));

    // Register Service Factory
    builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(context =>
    {
        var componentContext = context.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
        return t => { return componentContext.TryResolve(t, out var o) ? o : null; };
    });
}
```

And my ApplicationModule is:

```
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
       builder.RegisterType(typeof(JobSeekerRepository<JobSeeker>))
        .As(typeof(IJobSeekerRepository<JobSeeker>))
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

       builder.RegisterType<RequestManager>()
         .As<IRequestManager>()
         .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

       builder.RegisterType<JobSeekerContextSeed>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

       builder.RegisterType(typeof(JobSeekerMgmtEventService))
          .As(typeof(IJobSeekerMgmtEventService))
          .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

       // AddCreditCardCommand
       builder.RegisterType(typeof(IdentifiedCommandHandler<AddCreditCardCommand, CreditCardModel>))
              .As<IRequestHandler<IdentifiedCommand<AddCreditCardCommand, CreditCardModel>, CreditCardModel>>()
              .AsImplementedInterfaces();
    }
```

When I do the above and publish an event using Mediatr, it publishes the same event three times.  So then I commented out the JobSeekerRegisteredDomainEventRelayHandler registration in MediatorModule.  Once I did this then it only published the event twice.

I then commented out services.AddMediatr() and everything worked correctly - the event only got published once.

So now I am really confused - why does Mediatr still work even though I commented out AddMediatr()?  Why did it publish the event twice when it is uncommented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IMediatr` is still available because you (also) register it via below call in your code.

```
builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(IMediator).GetTypeInfo().Assembly)
    .AsImplementedInterfaces();
```

The `Mediatr` GitHub [wiki](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#autofac) provides the steps to follow when e.g. using `Autofac`.
There's also a full [example](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/master/samples/MediatR.Examples.Autofac/Program.cs) which is using the code above to register `IMediatr`.

That wiki shows you should make use of `AddMediatr` in case you're using the [ASP.NET Core DI container](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki#aspnet-core-or-net-core-in-general), which you are not.

---

You are also making multiple calls to Autofacs `RegisterAssemblyTypes` method, which is a [scanning](https://autofac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/scanning.html) one, meaning it registers all types in the corresponding assembly.
When you do that more than once for the same assembly, its `IMediatr` related types - e.g. command and notification handlers - fire more than once.
Make sure to make that call only once per assembly.